# Proving an inequality on polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of degree atmost $n$ and the $q(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ having  all it's zeros in $|z|\leq K, K\geq 1,$ with $|p(z)|\leq |q(z)|$ on $|z|=K$ Then how to prove $|p'(z)| \leq |q'(z)|$ on $|z|=K.?$

Comment: $p(z)=Large*z^n + SmallConstant$ and $q(z) =small*z^n + HugeGiantHumongousConstant$.

Comment: @fleablood Won't your $q$ have its roots in $|z|\le K$ only if $K$ is humongous in a contraproductive way?

Comment: Oh, maybe.... It was just a suggestion.  Actually I'm not sure I understand the OPs point about $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking is impossible as one can prove that if $\deg q=n, \deg p \le n,q$ has all its zeroes in the closed unit disc and $|p(z)| \le |q(z)|$ when $|z|=1$, then $|p'(z)| \le |q'(z)|$ when $|z| \ge 1$ (with equality for some $|z| >1$ iff $p=\lambda q, |\lambda|=1$.

Proof: assume $p \ne \lambda q, |\lambda|=1$ as otherwise nothing to prove and take $p^*, q^*$ the $n$ duals of $p,q$ w.r the unit circle (eg $q^*(z)=z^n\bar{q(\frac{1}{\bar z})}$ or if you want, reversing all the coefficients and conjugating them when the degree is $n$, while doing the same but starting at $z^n$ when the degree is less so if $q(z)=A_nz^n+...A_0, A_n \ne 0$, $q^*(z)=\bar A_0z^n+...\bar A_n$ etc

Now it is clear that $q^*$ has all zeroes on or outside the unit circle, while the inequality $|p| \le |q|$ on the unit circle means that all zeroes of $q$ on the unit circle are zeroes of $p$ with same or higher multiplicity, hence the same is true for $q^*,p^*$, so $\phi=\frac{p^*}{q^*}$ is analytic on the closed unit circle and actually even on a larger circle until we hit a zero of $q^*$ strictly outside. Now $|\phi| \le 1$ on the unit circle by the original inequality, hence $|\phi| \le 1$ inside and since by assumption $p \ne \alpha q$ we actually must have strict inequality inside the unit disc. So $|p^*| < |q^*|$ there, hence $p^*-cq^*$ doesn't cancel inside the unit disc when $|c| \ge 1$.

Note that if $A_n \ne 0, a_n$ are the degree $n$ coefficients of $q,p$ respectively, $\phi(0)=\frac{\bar a_n}{\bar A_n}$ hence $|a_n| <|A_n|$, so if we take now $p-cq$ with any $|c| \ge 1$, $p-cq$ is of degree $n$ and has all the zeroes inside the closed unit disc as otherwise the inversion shows there is a zero of $p^*-\bar cq^*$ inside the unit disc.

Gauss-Lucas now implies all the zeroes of $p'-cq'$ are inside the closed unit disc and since $|c| \ge 1$ arbitrary this obviously implies $|p'(z)| < |q'(z)|$ if $|z|>1$, hence by continuity, $|p'(z)| \le |q'(z)|$ if $|z|=1$

Comment: This is the case K=1. What about if K>1?

Comment: Just take the variable $w=\frac{z}{K}$. You get polynomials $p_1(w)=p(Kw)$ and same for $q_1$. They have same degree as $p,q$and satisfy the hypothesis for $|w|=1$. But $p_1'(w)=Kp'(z)$ and same for $q$ so the derivative inequality still holds